# Installing openCSV for Java. What do I do with a .gz file?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, opencsv

I'm trying to install `openCSV` for java and downloaded the files from sourceForge.  Unfortunately it's a .`gz` file and I'm not sure how to handle it.

(How do I get the .jar files to add to the path?)

Any suggestions?

I'm using windows 7 machine with netbeans and eclipse.

Comment: @DaveNewton: How would I do that?  My only experience w/ .gz files is in R and they are automatically handled by the installer.

Comment: ... Use WinZip, 7zip, or any other file compression utility.

Comment: Any free utilities you'd suggest?

Comment: I dunno, how about 7zip? This question is totally off-topic, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/) or [Winzip](http://www.winzip.com) to extract the content of the tar.gz. If you have cygwin, and cygwin bin directory is on your path environment variable you can use the command line to execute this:

```
tar xvzf thefile.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need some clarification about the file format:

- .tar is a file format for storing collections of files for distribution or archiving
- .gz is the file extension for files compressed using gzip

Open the tar.gz archive in [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and drill into the folder tree until you find the opencsv-2.3 folder and then extract.